# What is a moduli space of Calabi-Yau threefolds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, calabi-yau

A Calabi-Yau threefold is a compact Kahler threefold which is simply connected and has trivial canonical bundle.

So my question is as in the title. What is the moduli space of such objects? I'm interested in general info about how its geometry looks like, its irreducible components etc.

I do know a few examples of CY3s but mostly from algebraic geometry - a non-singular quintic in $ \mathbb{P}^4 $, or more generally, appropriate complete intersections in higher dimensional projective spaces / products of projective spaces.

The points of this supposed moduli space should correspond to isomorphism classes of CY3s. How is this space constructed?

Comment: By the Tian-Todorov Theorem, the local Kuranishi spaces are all smooth.  So connected components are irreducible.  The main open conjecture about the components is the Kawamata-Morrison Conjecture.

Comment: @Jason Starr thank you for this information. I would like to know how this space is constructed though. For example, I know about the moduli space of curves of genus g, or the moduli of stable sheaves on a surface. There are techniques to construct such spaces, via GIT. Is there something like this for CY3s?

Comment: There are better MO users than me to discuss this, but according to the Beauville-Bogomolov decomposition (closely related to the Berger-de Rham decomposition), such manifolds are finite group quotients of a complex torus, a product of a K3 surface and an elliptic curve, or an "irreducible Calabi-Yau manifold", i.e., one for which the Hodge numbers $h^{p,0}$ equal $0$ for $p=1,2$.  For the last class, all of these are projective.  So you can construct moduli stacks of these manifolds using Artin's algebraization theorems, cf. "Versal deformations and algebraic stacks".

Comment: So my 'simply connected' assumption rules out your first two classes of examples, right? And yes, I'm mainly looking for the irreducible ones. Looks like we don't have much understanding of those yet?

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  Certainly simply connected Calabi-Yau manifolds of dimension 3 have vanishing Hodge numbers $h^{p,0}$ for $p$ equal to 1 or 2.  This makes their moduli stacks easier to understand, not harder to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should mention that I'm just a PhD student who is more or less ignorant about stacks. The only stack I've dealt with is the moduli stack of elliptic curves.

Comment: Since the Hodge numbers $h^{1,0}$ and $h^{2,0}$ vanish, the stacks of Calabi-Yau threefolds can be glued together from "charts" that are of the form $H_{n,d}/\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)$, where $H_[n,d}$ is the open subscheme of the Hilbert scheme parameterizing closed subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^n$ that are smooth Calabi-Yau threefolds of degree $d$.  So the stacks are locally quite close to the scheme $H_{n,d}$.  By the Tian-Todorov Theorem, this scheme is smooth and quasi-projective.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you so much for your patience. I guess my exercise for now will be to prove that any CY3 with $ h^{1,0} = 0 = h^{2,0} $ is projective and then proceed.

Comment: These are projective because the second cohomology group $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ is purely $(1,1)$.  Since $H^2(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is dense in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$, and since the Kaehler cone is open in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$, it follows that there are elements of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Q})$ that are in the Kaehler cone.  Then, by the Kodaira embedding theorem, a suitably positive and divisible integer multiple of this class equals the first Chern class of a very ample invertible sheaf.  This is how you can embed the Calabi-Yau threefold in $\mathbb{P}^n$, and thus get a point of $H_{n,d}$.

Comment: Wonderful. So any compact Kahler manifold with $ h^{2,0} = 0 $ is projective. Your proof shows that it has nothing to do with being a threefold or $ h^{1,0} = 0 $.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  None of these arguments is my proof -- I have seen this argument repeated in lectures many times (unfortunately I cannot immediately think of a written reference, but I am sure that there is a reference).